# Spring Security LDAP Changes After 5.7

Tags: spring-security, ldap

I am trying to understand the steps to support LDAP with Spring security...replacing our current basic authentication. Recently I made the changes to support the deprecation of the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and all is working fine. So now I want to swap out the basic authentication AuthenticationManager or AuthenticationProvider with their LDAP equivalents. There are several websites with partial information and I cant quite put the pieces together.

So I am starting with the spring guide on authenticating ldap (https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-authenticating-ldap) I took the "complete" example, modified for our version of Spring Boot 2.7.5 and the app starts and validates fine. I tried updating the example according to several websites from :

```
@Autowired
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
            .contextSource()
                .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=springframework,dc=org")
                .and()
            .passwordCompare()
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
                .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
```

To :

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedLdapServerContextSourceFactoryBean contextSourceFactoryBean() {
    EmbeddedLdapServerContextSourceFactoryBean contextSourceFactoryBean =
            EmbeddedLdapServerContextSourceFactoryBean.fromEmbeddedLdapServer();
    contextSourceFactoryBean.setPort(0);
    return contextSourceFactoryBean;
}   

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(BaseLdapPathContextSource contextSource) {
    LdapPasswordComparisonAuthenticationManagerFactory factory = new LdapPasswordComparisonAuthenticationManagerFactory(
            contextSource, new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    factory.setUserDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people");
    factory.setPasswordAttribute("pwd");  
    return factory.createAuthenticationManager();
}
```

Thinking this closer to the recommendations and closer to what I would be using in our real project. Now when I try to build ... the test phase keeps failing with the following stack trace

```
ERROR[m] loginWithValidUserThenAuthenticated  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in class path resource [com/example/authenticatingldap/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'authenticationManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextSourceFactoryBean': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load LDIF classpath*:*.ldif
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextSourceFactoryBean': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load LDIF classpath*:*.ldif
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load LDIF classpath*:*.ldif
Caused by: com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPException: An entry with DN 'dc=springframework,dc=org' already exists in the server.
```

I am using the same ldif file that worked with the other configuration. The code follows the other examples and recommendation but the embedded LDAP server wont load the file. Has anyone seen and solved this problem? Once this is working, do we simply remove the Embedded LDAP bean and somehow point the configuration to the real LDAP server?

Comment: The [LDAP Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html#_ldap_authentication) example in the [5.8 migration guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/index.html) seems close to what you have, so I think you're close. The issue with the LDIF file doesn't seem familiar. Here's [an example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/main/servlet/java-configuration/authentication/username-password/ldap/src/main/resources/users.ldif) that I believe works. Perhaps the embedded LDAP provider changed?

Comment: What happens if you use the example I linked above?